# Can Tuleap link to GitHub repositories?

Tags: github, tuleap

We have been using Tuleap for workload management for some time, but recently we started using GitHub for source control/management.

I know Tuleap can integrate with git on the Tuleap server itself, but I need to know if it can be configured to work with GitHub hosted repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Going through its documentation, it seems **Tuleap only supports self-hosted git repositories**. Regarding externally hosted git repositories, Tuleap offers the possibility for [mirroring](https://docs.tuleap.org/administration-guide/application-management/plugins/git.html).

You can manage Git mirrors in Tuleap by:

1. Access ADMINISTRATION;
2. Scroll down to the PLUGINS section on the left side menu and click Git;
3. Click on the MIRRORS tab.

[image: Tuleap Git mirrors setup]